# Problem with using of xlmread command in Octave

Tags: xml, io, signals, octave

I am trying to use a command xmlread in Octave, but unfortunately, I get an error:

```
error: xmlread: no xercesImpl.jar and/or xml-apis.jar > v2.11.0 in javaclasspath
```

error is called from:

```
xmlread at line 71 column 7

XML_LOAD at line 6 column 6
```

IO package was used before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation for `xmlread`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/xmlread.html), you'll find:

```
Function File: node = xmlread (fname)

    Parse an xml file fname using Xerces Java library and return a Java object representing an XML DOM document.

    Octave does not ship with a Xerces library so you should take care of adding the required .jar files to your java_path, e.g:

    javaaddpath ("/path/to/xerces-2_11_0/xercesImpl.jar");
    javaaddpath ("/path/to/xerces-2_11_0/xml-apis.jar");

    xmlread will check for Java support and proper xerces Java libraries in the javaclasspath until the check passes, or if it is called without arguments...
```

The current version of this Java library can be obtained from:

http://xerces.apache.org/

Specifically, selecting Downloads, scrolling down to Binary Distributions, and selecting the "Xerces2 Java 2.XX.YY - zip" for download (XX and YY being the latest versions).  The file can be unzipped to a folder, and the two .jar files mentioned above will be in the base of that folder tree.

The javaaddpath commands above (edited to point to those files on your system) can then be added to either the script you're building or your [`.octaverc` (startup commands) file](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Startup-Files.html) in your user or home folder so they run every time you use Octave. (I've also seen cases where they just keep those two .jar files in every working folder using them, and the javaaddpath points to those local files.)

Comment: for those coming from Matlab, I believe it bundles it's own java version and therefore includes the java libraries used by it's version of xmlread

Comment: Yep, Matlab ships with a JVM and a bunch of third-party Java libs, including Xerces and related Java XML libraries. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14684wWyS9FnS-MYD56ISJdmw9Csdymhs7GB-9nbeZz8/edit#gid=0 for a full list. I haven't been able to determine the exact version of their Xerces, but it's probably ancient; MathWorks never updates their Java dependencies. Their XML Java setup also appears to be subtly broken, but AFAICT that only affects writing XML, not reading it.